# MASS:: fitdistr negative binomial with weights in R

Tags: weighted

We are carrying out an Operational Risk study, in particular we are fitting a severity frequency function with a negative binomial as follows:

```
# Negative Binomial Fitting
fit = MASS::fitdistr(datosf$Freq,"negative binomial")[[1]]
BN_s <- fit[1]
BN_mu <- fit[2]
# fitdistr parametrises the BN with size and mu, we calculate the parameter p as size/(size+mu)
BN_prob<-fit[1]/(fit[1]+fit[2])

# scale size to model annual frequency
BN_size= BN_s*f_escala

# goodness-of-fit test
chi_2_test = chisq.test(datosf$Freq,rnbinom(n=l,size=BN_s,prob=BN_prob))
# goodness-of-fit plot
nbinom = function(x)dnbinom(x, size = BN_s, mu = BN_mu)
hist(datosf$Freq, freq=FALSE, nclass=50)
curve(nbinom, from=0, to=max(datosf$Freq), n=max(datosf$Freq)+1, add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

In the data frame datosf$Freq we have the frequency (of the historical series) grouped monthly.

Currently, we have the objective of weighting these years according to the time horizon using the function:

```
w(t) = 1.05 - t/20 where t is the number of years and t=1,....,10
```

i.e. the objective is to maximise the following likelihood function:

```
L(x_i,\theta) = \prod_{i} w_i f(x_i,\theta)
```

Where x_i is the frequency and f(x_i) is the negative binomial density function.

How can we readapt the code to include the weights w_i?

Thank you very much!